# print values between words PHP

Tags: php

Made in a facility that uses allergens (GLUTEN, SOY, CELERY, NUTS). Energy value: 971kJ /234kcal. 100g of product contains: fat 18.1g, including saturated fatty acids 6g.

I need to display the calorie values.

There may be a space before `234kcal`, or it may be, as it is now, merged with `/`
Maybe everything is merged at once `971kJ/234kcal`, or maybe there are gaps
`971kJ / 234kcal`

I need to get out anyway  only Kcal value.

```
$info_in_text  = "Made in a facility that uses allergens (GLUTEN, SOY, CELERY, NUTS). Energy value: 971kJ /234kcal. 100g of product contains: fat 18.1g, including saturated fatty acids 6g.";
$pieces = explode(" ", $info_in_text);
foreach( $pieces as $key => $value )
{
    if($pieces[$key] == 'value:' )
    {
        echo $pieces[$key+2];
     }
}
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work correctly. It is necessary that in any case it displays only calorie values (kcal ). in this case, displays if there are no spaces or not everything is merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `preg_match_all()` with a regular expression we can try:

```php
$input = "Made in a facility that uses allergens (GLUTEN, SOY, CELERY, NUTS). Energy value: 971kJ /234kcal. 100g of product contains: fat 18.1g, including saturated fatty acids 6g.";
preg_match_all("/\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*k?cal\b/", $input, $result);
print_r($result[0][0]);  // 234kcal
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` an integer or decimal number
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `k?cal` match `cal` or `kcal`
- `\b` word boundary

Comment: Thank you so much. I always got confused in these expressions, so I tried to avoid them, but not in this case, it seems ... thanks